# In Django is it possible to delete a range of data from a table whose integer values sum up to a certain value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Example I have this model
models.py

```
class Share(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(
        Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='share')
    week = models.ForeignKey(
        WeekModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='share')
    month = models.ForeignKey(
        MonthModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='share', blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.ForeignKey(
        YearModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='share', blank=True, null=True)
    shares = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    jamii = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    fine = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    #weeknumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    monthname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    years = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'share'
        unique_together = [("member", "week")]
        ordering = ['member__user__username']
        natsorted(ordering)
```

Is it possible to query by date the values that add up to a given integer from the shares field and delete them?

Comment: Describe this further. Do you get the given integer ahead of time? or do you pick a particular Share record, then query Share ordered by created_at date? then walk through  the records, keeping a tally of the sum, deleting as you go until you reach that number?

Comment: @AMG Thank you for your response. Yes, you get the integer(sum) ahead of time then walk through the records(summing up integers in the shares field), keeping a tally of the sum(which is the integer you got ahead of time), deleting as you go until you reach that number(Integer you got ahead of time).